# What is the geometric interpretation of a (local/global trivial and vector) bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

**Local trivial bundle**

We call $\pi : \: E \rightarrow M$ (where $E$, $M$, $F$ are manifolds) a local trivial bundle with fiber $F$ if:

1. $\pi$ is a surjection
2. $\forall_{x \in M} \: \:  \exists_{\text{neighborhood }U} \: : \: f_U : \: \pi^{-1} (U) \rightarrow U \times F, \quad p e_1 : \: U \times F \rightarrow U, \quad \pi : \: \pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U$, where $f_U$ is a diffeomorphism, and $p e_1$ is the projection on the first variable (?)

**Global trivial bundle**

It's a local trivial bundle, with the exception that $E = M \times F$

**Vector bundle**

$\pi : \: E \rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle, if:

1. $F = \mathbb{R}^n$
2. $\forall_{x \in M} \: \exists_{\text{Atlas }A\text{ na }M} \: : \: \text{Maps }(U, \phi), (V, \psi) \text{ in }x\text{ belong to }A$

---

Those definitions are very abstract for me, and I can't find a visual/geometric interpretation of what all of that means.

Could anyone (maybe on an easy example) show me this?

Comment: Start by thinking about a Möbius strip (projecting to a circle) and an (infinite or finite height) cylinder (also projecting to a circle).

Comment: I honestly don't see the connection between this and bundles

Comment: Well, you should. Go through your definitions and see how they apply in all three cases. Do you have a trivial bundle in one of the cases?